# LoL update keeps resetting

Tags: league-of-legends

Whenever I try to install the league update it gets a small part of the update done and it stops the update and resets the progress. I’ve freed up more than enough space for the update and used the hex tech repair tool, I’ve even deleted and reinstalled LoL multiple times. Can anyone help?

Comment: Any error message or it just stops? Also, when it stop did you just let it run? sometimes the LoL installer stops for a few minutes to uncompress/install what it just downloaded, but it looks like it just stopped. I guess let it run overnight if you can, but if you already tried that, i'll check if something else could be done.

Answer (score 1):

You might have already tried these, but here is what LoL support has to say about installs that stop:

https://support-leagueoflegends.riotgames.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005275348-Can-t-install-League-of-Legends

> The League of Legends installation may fail if you don't have administrator access to your computer, or if something is interfering with your network connection.
>
> ## Update Windows
>
> If your version of Windows needs updating, you may have trouble installing League. Just search for “Windows Update” in your Start menu and click “Check for updates”.
>
> ## Run installation as administrator
>
> First, make sure you've downloaded the game from the League site. Then locate the file, right-click the installer, and select "Run as Administrator".
>
> ## Temporarily disable your firewall
>
> If you've installed a third-party firewall, try disabling them before installing or starting a patch. Windows comes with its own firewall, which you can disable by following these steps:
>
> - Click on Start
> - Click on Control Panel
> - Click on System and Security
> - Click on Windows Firewall
> - Click on Turn Windows Firewall on or off (You may be prompted to enter the Admin password at this step)
> - Under each network location, select the "Turn off Windows Firewall" option
>
> ## Still having issues?
>
> If there are no firewalls active on your computer and you're still unable to install League, send us a ticket and we'll take a closer look!